# equivalent of jQuery's "load" in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am trying to find an equivalent for the following jQuery javascript:

```
var x1 = setInterval(function() { $('#status').load("processor.php", {value:'name'} );}, 5000 );
```

I need to use Prototype for other applications on the page, and when I throw both jQuery and Prototype libraries in there they will not cooperate.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype's Ajax function "periodical updater" is what you're looking for:

http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/periodicalupdater.html